# Using eclipse, can i make just a "scratch pad" page for java?

Tags: java

Sometimes i just want to write out some quick java to see if my algorithm works.

Maybe I am preparing for an interview! Maybe I just want to see how my code  is running.

At these times, I typically make a new java file, and save it in a project i've marked called "scratchyCat". Don't judge me.

However, 99% of the code there is useless, I don't need to save it or ever even see it again. Does eclipse have some shortcut to create a java page that i can just  write code on, compile and run, and then delete?

Alternatively, is there some website  (like jsfiddle) that would let me do the same for java?

Comment: There's http://ideone.com/

Comment: Any text editor will do. `cd $(mktemp -d) && edit Test.java && javac Test.java && java -cp . Test && rm -rf $PWD`.  I believe it is always good to keep being able to do simple stuff without using a heavy IDE.  It reminds one of how the machine works.

Comment: public class Foo { public static void main ( String [] args ) { } } // there's your template class to write your test code in...anything more than that is too specific to be saved as a template

Comment: I found this to be helpful: http://nzpcmad.blogspot.com/2005/11/eclipse-writing-java-snippets-in.html  BTW, I'm now going to name all my scratch code scratchyCat...